# How to Give Server side validations in MVC using alert message?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, partial-views

I my MVC Application I open a partial view in a  jQuery dialog box On a button click event when I submit my form and my server side validation gets failed.

Now, I want to show a alert message from server side on popup window for eg.Alert message. Now please tell me Friends how to open a alert  message on popup window when I click on alert okay button my alert should be closed and my
 dialog box should not be closed and data in dialog box should be retained in case of server side failure validations.

Dialog Box opening code on click of a button code as Follows:

```
  $("body").on("click", "#modal2", function (e) {

                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
                    title: 'Add Ticket',
                    autoOpen: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    width: '65%',
                    height: 400,
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: false,
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).load(url);
                        $('.ui-widget-overlay').addClass('custom-overlay');
                    },
                    close: function (event, ui) {


                        $(this).dialog('close');




                        $('.ui-widget-overlay').removeClass('custom-overlay');
                    }
                });

                $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
                return false;
            });
```

The data shown in Dialog box through an ID code as follows:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Ticket(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int suserid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"]);
                var Station = cn.usp_FlightsStatusGrid(suserid).Where(x => x.ID == id).ToList();
                //ViewBag.Station = new SelectList(Station, "StationID", "Station");
                ViewData["Employees"] = cn.usp_EditmodeFlightDetailInformation(id).FirstOrDefault();

                ViewBag.fhid = id;
                List<usp_ErrorRecordsList_Result> model = cn.usp_ErrorRecordsList(id).ToList();

                int a = cn.usp_ErrorRecordsList(id).Where(x => x.POI == "").ToList().Count;
                return PartialView("_AddTicket", model);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string sActionName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
            string sControllerName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            cn.usp_ErrorLogDetails(sControllerName + "/" + sActionName, ex.Message);
            Session["ErrorMsg"] = ex.Message;
            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Error");
        }

        return View();

    }
```

Form Submission Code as Follows:

```
   $("#btnSave").click(function () {


                    var retval = ISVALID();
                    //ISVALID();
                    if (retval == true)
                    {

                        $('#myForm2').submit();

                    }
                    else {

                        return false;
                    }

                });
```

Data Saving Through Post Method as Follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Ticket(List<UCR.Models.usp_ErrorRecordsList_Result> lstmissingrecord,int Id)
{
    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["IDmissingticket"]);
    List<usp_ErrorRecordsList_Result> model = cn.usp_ErrorRecordsList(ID).Where(x => x.POI != null).ToList();
    var updatedticket = lstmissingrecord.Where(x => x.TicketCurrency != null && x.POI != null && x.AdultInfant != null && x.TransitPax != null).ToList();

    int suserid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"]);
    int count = 0;
    string scurrencymsg = "Please provide correct information for Ticket No.";
    foreach (var ticket in updatedticket)
    {

        if (!(cn.tblCountries.Any(x => x.CurrencyCode == ticket.TicketCurrency.ToUpper().Trim()) && cn.tblCities.Any(x => x.CityCode == ticket.POI.ToUpper().Trim())))
        {
            scurrencymsg += ticket.TicketNo + ",";
            string SuccessTickeMsg = scurrencymsg.Substring(0, scurrencymsg.Length - 1);

            TempData["TickeMsg"] = SuccessTickeMsg; // Validation Gets Failed.And I want to have a alert message Here and I click on  alert ok button my alrert box should get closed but Dialog box should not get closed.And Data should get retained in Dialog Box.
            return RedirectToAction("Uploadpassengers", "Home");

        }

    }


    foreach (var ticket in updatedticket)
    {


        //if (cn.tblCountries.Any(x => x.CurrencyCode == ticket.TicketCurrency.ToUpper().Trim()) == true && cn.tblCities.Any(x => x.CityCode == ticket.POI.ToUpper().Trim()))
        //{

        cn.usp_InsertTicketmissingdetailInformationsbyuser(Convert.ToInt32(ticket.PaxID), ticket.TicketNo, ticket.PaxName, ticket.TicketCurrency.ToUpper().Trim(), ticket.AdultInfant.ToUpper().Trim(), ticket.TransitPax.ToUpper().Trim(), suserid, ticket.POI.ToUpper().Trim(), ticket.DateOfIssue);

        cn.SaveChanges();
        count = count + 1;
        //}
        //   else
        //{

        //    scurrencymsg += ticket.TicketNo + ",";


        //}
    }
    if (lstmissingrecord.Count == count)
    {
        cn.usp_StatusUpdation(Id);
        cn.SaveChanges();
    }

    if (scurrencymsg == "Please provide correct information for Ticket No.")
    {
        string SuccessTickeMsg = ConstantMsg.C1009;

        TempData["TickeMsg"] = SuccessTickeMsg;
        return RedirectToAction("Uploadpassengers", "Home");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Uploadpassengers", "Home");
    //else {
    //    string SuccessTickeMsg = scurrencymsg.Substring(0, scurrencymsg.Length - 1);
    //    var response = new Response(true, SuccessTickeMsg);
    //    return Json(response.v2);
    //}
}
```